# Person account in apex : fill in contact fields

Tags: apex, person-accounts

In apex I try to create a person account. For the field linked to the account it's ok, but when I want to fill the contact field (a field like `myfield__pc`) it does not work. Here is basically what I did :

```
Account compte = new Account();
compte.BillingStreet = 'test;
compte.BillingCity = 'test';
compte.Job__pc = 'myjob';
//etc, and i insert the account
```

In salesforce I can visualize the new account, all the fields are filled except the ones concerning the contact (in this case, Job__pc is not filled...)

How can I fill theses kind of fields ?

Comment: I did a test and it just works. Is there an error you are facing? Also can you post your complete code as this one seems just an example.

Comment: Did you set the correct record type? That could cause a problem.